# Can not resolve method hasChildQuery by using spring-data-elasticsearch?

Tags: spring-data-elasticsearch

```
QueryBuilder query = hasChildQuery(Province.CHILD_TYPE, QueryBuilders.termQuery("name", name.toLowerCase()), ScoreMode.None);
    List<Province> parents = operations.queryForList(new NativeSearchQuery(query), Province.class);
    return false;
```

I am using spring-data-elasticsearch.
I don't know what class to import by resolving this method "hasChildQuery"?
Anyone has encounter this kind of problem? This is my first time using spring-data-elasticsearch.
@Mohsin Husen @Joanna

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
QueryBuilder query = QueryBuilders.hasChildQuery(Province.CHILD_TYPE, QueryBuilders.termQuery("name", name.toLowerCase()), ScoreMode.None);
```

with following imports:

```
import org.elasticsearch.index.query.QueryBuilders;
import org.apache.lucene.search.join.ScoreMode;
```